# Executing a hidden query in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to execute a query from VBA, but I don't want the query to be shown to the user. I just want to execute it so that my VBA code can get the results and present them on a form. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you compiling your code and giving the user an mde or accde? If so, life becomes very easy.

Answer (score 1):

I've mosty answered my own question! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966%28v=office.15%29.aspx was a great help, here's my code:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("GetVisitDetails")
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![Visitor Management]![VRN]") = 1
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

I can then use the record set. Now I just need to work out how to get the value from the form.

Answer (score -3):

I assume you dont want a message box shown to the user eg "You are about to update 3 records..."

You can use the docmd.setwarnings

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Your Query Name", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` is never good advice, or a suitable replacement, for proper Error Handling.